# Namespaces with per-logger log levels specification

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've recently been testing ROS2 galactic and tried using the new per-logger log levels [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Releases/Release-Galactic-Geochelone.html#ability-to-specify-per-logger-log-levels). I am using it with namespaces and couldn't get it to work. Is there a way to use it with namespaces?

The command I am using is:

```
ros2 run robot_control vehicle --ros-args -r __ns:=/drone_0 --log-level vehicle:=DEBUG
```

I've also tried the following after using `ros2 node list` to get the node names:

```
ros2 run robot_control vehicle --ros-args -r __ns:=/drone_0 --log-level /drone_0/vehicle:=DEBUG
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381604/namespaces-with-per-logger-log-levels-specification/) by [Blake McHale](https://answers.ros.org/users/61567/blake-mchale/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2021-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you need to do this:

```
ros2 run robot_control vehicle --ros-args -r __ns:=/drone_0 --log-level drone_0.vehicle:=DEBUG
```

To get it to work.

To test this, I modified the `talker` demo in the `demo_nodes_cpp` package, like this:

```
diff --git a/demo_nodes_cpp/src/topics/talker.cpp b/demo_nodes_cpp/src/topics/talker.cpp
index 30f97a0..01756d0 100644
--- a/demo_nodes_cpp/src/topics/talker.cpp
+++ b/demo_nodes_cpp/src/topics/talker.cpp
@@ -44,6 +44,7 @@ public:
       {
         msg_ = std::make_unique<std_msgs::msg::String>();
         msg_->data = "Hello World: " + std::to_string(count_++);
+        RCLCPP_DEBUG(this->get_logger(), "Publishing: '%s'", msg_->data.c_str());
         RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Publishing: '%s'", msg_->data.c_str());
         // Put the message into a queue to be processed by the middleware.
         // This call is non-blocking.
```

And to reproduce what you were trying to do, I did this:

```
$ ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker --ros-args -r __ns:=/drone_0 --log-level talker:=DEBUG
[DEBUG] [1625186542.873545147] [talker]: Load library libtopics_library.so
[DEBUG] [1625186542.875355119] [talker]: Instantiate class rclcpp_components::NodeFactoryTemplate<demo_nodes_cpp::Talker>
1625186542.876201 [87]     talker: using network interface enp0s5 (udp/10.211.55.6) selected arbitrarily from: enp0s5, docker0
[INFO] [1625186543.880863775] [drone_0.talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 1'
...

$ ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker --ros-args -r __ns:=/drone_0 --log-level drone_0.talker:=DEBUG
1625186556.836825 [87]     talker: using network interface enp0s5 (udp/10.211.55.6) selected arbitrarily from: enp0s5, docker0
[DEBUG] [1625186557.841640933] [drone_0.talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 1'
[INFO] [1625186557.841909375] [drone_0.talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 1'
```

Note that even though the node name is `/drone_0/talker` (as reported by `ros2 node list`), the logger name is separated by `.` instead of `/`.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2021-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Blake McHale](https://answers.ros.org/users/61567/blake-mchale/) on 2021-07-02**:
Thanks! That works!